# Magento 2: How to load my custom js file after footer?

Tags: magento2, javascript, external-script

**JS File Path:** `web->js->swap.js`

**default_head_block.xml**

```
    <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="swapjs">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="js/swap.js"></script>]]></argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

File path not found `404 Error`. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Below way..

You can do it with layout

```
    <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
        <block class="\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="You_Module::js.phtml" name="module_js"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

and in js.phtml

```
<scrip src="example.com/jp2/test.js" />
```

Or

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
        <block type="core/text" name="new-descriptive-name">
        <action method="setText">
            <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mywebsite.com/myfolder/my-javascript.min.js"></script></text>
        </action>
        </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: got the error Object DOMDocument should be created.

Comment: @MasudShaikh i have updated my answer

Comment: Ok, I will check.

Answer (score 1):

Add an external JS in the following way :

Try this,

Add your custom js in the following path.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-name/web/js/nameofjs.js

then you need to add **requirejs-config.js** to the following path.

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-name/requirejs-config.js

then add the following code in it

```
 var config = {
    paths: {            
            'your_js_name' : 'js/nameofjs', 
        },                                                                
    shim: {
    'your_js_name': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
  }
};
```

and add the below code to load custom **js**, In your case it would be **footer.phtml** in **Magento_Theme** folder on your theme

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme-name/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer.phtml

```
<script>
require(['jquery','your_js_name'],function($) {
$(window).load(function () {
     /*alert('load from external jquery');*/
});});
</script>
```

This would trigger the JS after footer is rendered. Hope this helps.