# magento 2 how to load custom script after the summary page is loaded

Tags: magento2

I'm unable to load custom scripts after the page is loaded completely. I tried to load using require.js

Comment: can you share what is the exact error that, you are facing?

Comment: Hi I want to hide specific product from checkout summary page after it loads. But my custom js loads before the cart is loaded fully so that whatever I have added in my custom js is waste as the checkout is loading slowly(knockout js)

Comment: how can I add screen shots here? is there any way ?

Comment: When I visit the checkout page, the checkout summary loads after my custom.js file. This means when i'm trying to hide specific product(free product) from the summary this is not working.

Is there any way of me setting my custom.js file as the last file that gets loaded?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293121/magento-2-how-to-load-my-custom-js-file-after-footer  you can follow this thread to load js after magento js